# how to force stop Intellij on linux

Tags: linux, intellij-idea, scratch-file

I am using a scratch file for some Kotlin work.

- I accidentally created an endless loop in one of my functions and ran the file, so Intellij is not responding.
- There is no button for stopping the execution of the scratch file and even if there were, that wouldn't work because Intellij is not responding to mouse clicks.

How do I force stop or restart Intellij in this case?

Comment: I can minimize/maximize but I can't close the ide

Comment: What OS? You can kill it via task manager or `taskkill` in windows. `kill -9 pid` in mac/linux

Answer (score 37):

You can kill the process by name using

```
pkill -9 intellij
```

or by

```
killall -9 intellij
```

or even

```
kill -9 $(ps aux | grep intellij | awk '{print $2}')
```

Comment: Didn't work for me, but `pkill -9 java` or `killall -9 java` respectively did. Use with care at own responsibility.

Comment: Inspired by your last command with the pure hate of awk, here is a bash script for the job:
`arr=($(ps aux | grep intellij)) && kill -9 ${arr[1]}`

Answer (score 9):

You first need to find Intellij's process id:

```
ps -f | grep -i intellij
```

and then kill the process id (`PID`):

```
kill -9 PID
```

Comment: grep -i just to avoid the CrAzYCamelCase naming

Answer (score 9):

You can use `xkill`
then move the cursor from `X` to the window you need for example with (ide)
This works provided that you are not completely frozen OS

Answer (score 5):

Already good answers are given above.

Another great way to find IntelliJ `PID` is to use `htop` command on Linux.

1. Install `htop` with the command: `sudo apt install htop`
2. Run `htop` in terminal
3. In the tabular format, `PID` is associated with each process including `IntelliJ`.
4. Run `kill -9 <pid_of_intellij>` to `kill` the `IntelliJ` process.

Comment: htop is great and it's enhanced version of top

Answer (score 1):

I tried with intellij but it doesn't work. On my ubuntu this command is working `pkill -9 idea`